# Secure cookies option in Express - how to access

Tags: node.js, express, http, cookies, https

In a node app, I want to use cookies to read data. If I want to make a cookie using the options:

`res.cookie('user', '123', { signed: true, httpOnly: true, secure: true }`

and later read the cookie in a node endpoint/controller:

`router.get('/test', testHandler)`

```
function testHandler(req, res){
   // how to read the secure cookie here?
}
```

how can I access this secure cookie on my local machine? Would I have to set up an https server locally to be able to read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do `req.session`

Remember if you set the `secure` attribute to true, the connection has to be made over HTTPS, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Yeah that is it. Connection wasn't being made over https on local development, so added HTTPS server to local. Thank you!